# want to Rename Images In Bulk in Linux

Tags: linux, rename, images

I have more than 1 million images with name of

```
love-images-250x120.jpg
7788855441122-love-images-250x120.jpg
us-wallpapers33344.jpg
77441144desktop-wallpapers.jpg
desktop-wallpapers1144141411.jpg
```

I want to rename like this:

```
love-images.jpg
love-images-1.jpg
us-wallpapers.jpg
desktop-wallpapers.jpg
desktop-wallpapers-1.jpg
```

I am using this script:

```
for f in [0-9]*; do mv "$f" "`echo $f | -f sed 's/^[0-9]*\W*//'`"; done
```

But this code stops when 2 images have same name. Is there any way to perform this action?

Comment: This is somewhat complicated for a Shell script. Don't use `sed` for this. Use Perl or Python.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105568/want-to-rename-images-in-bulk-in-linux

Comment: @shivams A shell script can take you a long way :-)

Comment: Perhaps if you can use some words to describe the transformations that you wish to occur, it would be clearer what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Python in the following manner:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import glob
import re
import os
from collections import Counter

origNames = glob.glob('*jpg')

finalNames = []
for i in origNames:
    for old, new in [(r'\d+x\d+', ''), (r'\d', ''),(r'^\W+', ''),(r'-*\.-*', '.'), (r'\.jpg$', '')]:
        i = re.sub(old, new, i)
    finalNames.append(i)

counts = Counter(finalNames)
for s,num in counts.items():
    if num > 1:
        for suffix in range(1, num + 1):
            finalNames[finalNames.index(s)] = s + str(suffix)

print(origNames, finalNames)

for i,j in zip(origNames, finalNames):
    os.rename(i,j+".jpg")
```

Comment: @Shoabch Accept this answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, the solution could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

for fn_old in *.jpg; do

  i=0
  fn_new=${fn_old##+([-0-9])}                       # strip leading number sequence in basename 
  fn_new=${fn_new/%[-0-9]*([-0-9x]).jpg/.jpg}       # strip trailing number sequence in basename

  while [[ -e $fn_new ]]; do                        # see if proposed name already exists
    i=$((i+1))                                      # doublure counter
    fn_new=${fn_new/%*([-0-9]).jpg/-$i.jpg}         # try new filename with updated number
  done

  echo "$fn_old" -- "$fn_new"
  mv   "$fn_old" "$fn_new"

done
```

Be careful with the `mv` command. You may want to comment it out (or replace it with a `cp`) on a first run, just to see if the renaming scheme is what you want/expect.

For an explanation of the shell patterns and string manipulations, see:
[Bash pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) and [Bash string manipulations](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).